# Natural extension of the Gauss map

Tags: nt.number-theory, ergodic-theory, continued-fractions

Let $G:(0,1)\to(0,1)$ be the Gauss map, i.e., $G(x)=\left\{\frac1{x}\right\}$, which is known to act as the shift on the space of continued fraction expansions.

**Question.** Is there an explicit expression for the natural extension of $G$ in $\mathbb R^2$? What about its density?

Comment: The paper “A continued fraction titbit” by Mike Keane (Fractals 3 (1995), 641-650) constructs a map that, if I remember correctly, is easily seen to be the natural extension of the Gauss map, and also derives the invariant density based on fairly simple geometric considerations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was already mentioned by Christophe Leuridan for classical continued fraction
we have extended Gauss measure
$$d\overline{\nu}(x,y)=\frac{1}{\log2}\cdot\frac{dx\,dy}{(1+xy)^2}=\frac{1}{\log2}\cdot\begin{vmatrix} 1 & \mp x\\
\pm y & 1
\end{vmatrix}^{-2} dx\,dy,\qquad (x,y)\in[0,1]^2,$$
which is invariant under the map
$$\overline{T}:(x,y)\to\begin{cases}(\{1/x\},([1/x]+y)^{-1},&\text{ if }x\ne 0;\\
(x,y),&\text{ if }x= 0.
\end{cases}$$
Details can be found in the book
*M. Iosifescu and C. Kraaikamp, Metrical theory of continued fractions, 2002.*

From geometrical point of view this extended Gauss measure describes the distribution of reduced Voronoi bases $(b_1,b_2)$ with $b_1=(1,\mp x)$, $b_2=(\pm y,1)$ on the boundary of the unit square.

In dimension $3$ something similar is knowт for Voronoi-Minkowski continued fractions(see [Three-dimensional continued fractions and Kloosterman sums](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/RM2015v070n03ABEH004953/meta)). The measure has the form
$$\mathrm{const} \int_{\Pi}\frac{d\alpha'd\beta'd\gamma'}{(\det X)^3},$$
where $X=\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & \alpha_2' & \pm\alpha_3'\\
-\beta_1' & 1 & \beta_3'\\
     \gamma_1'&-\gamma_2'&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$ are matricies of reduced Minkowski bases and
$\alpha'=(\alpha_2',\alpha_3')$,
$\beta'=(\beta_1',\beta_3')$,
$\gamma'=(\gamma_1',\gamma_2')$.

Comment: See also Theorem 8.3.1 in Dajani and Kalle's book A first course in ergodic theory https://www.routledge.com/A-First-Course-in-Ergodic-Theory/Dajani-Kalle/p/book/9780367226206

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer.

I imagine that you mean a map $\overline{G}$ which sends $([0;a_1,a_2,\ldots],[0;a_0,a_{-1},\ldots])$ on $([0;a_2,a_3,\ldots],[0;a_1,a_0,\ldots])$. If yes, we have a simple formula
$$\overline{G}(x,y) = \big(\{1/x\},1/(\lfloor 1/x \rfloor + y)\big).$$
The probability measure on the set of all sequences $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ will be the stationary extension of the probability measure on the set of all sequences $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$. I guess that there will be an invariant density measure on $[0,1[^2$, like the Gauss measure for $G$ on $[0,1[$, since the sequence $(A_n)_{n \ge 1}$ of partial quotients associated to a random real chosen according to the Gauss measure is very close to be an i.i.d. sequence, but I have no idea on whether it has a simple expression or not.